# tikz-qtree align leaves at bottom of first line (multi-line leaves)

Tags: tikz-qtree

I'm trying to create trees using the `tikz-qtree` package where some leaves have additional information. However, I want the leaves to be aligned at the base of the first line. The MWE will show the issues I've ran into:

(1) If I set the `anchor=base`, the leaves align vertically at the very bottom, and I don't want the additional information to be considered when aligning vertically.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{%
            every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=base}, %align leaves at bottom
        }%
        
        \Tree
        [.Root
            Tall
            {no\\add' info}
        ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(2) If I change `anchor=north`, the leaves align at the very top. This is closer to what I want. However, the problem with this is that words/letters that are "taller" (eg, l,t,f) have a higher ceiling(?), so the words are slightly misaligned, as shown below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{%
            every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}, %align leaves at bottom
        }%
        
        \Tree
        [.Root
            Tall
            {no\\add' info}
        ]
    \end{tikzpicture}icture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In this second example, the top of "T" and "n" are vertically aligned. Is there a way to get "Tall" and "no" to align vertically at the base of these two words, ignoring the additional information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

A simple solution is add `\vphantom{f}` to the branch with "no":

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{%
every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}, %align leaves at bottom
        }%

        \Tree
        [.Root
            Tall
            {no\vphantom{f}\\add' info} % <---
        ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit (1):**

With use of the  `forest` package you will not have problems with aligning nides:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
    inner sep=1pt,
    align=center,
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north
            }
[Root
    [Tall]
    [no \\add' info]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Compilation result is the same as before:

[image]

**Edit (2):**

Using forest you can define its styles in preamble by `\forestset`:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{  % <---
  my tree/.style={%
for tree={inner sep = 1pt, % if you liked
          align=center,
          parent anchor=south,
          child anchor=north
                  }
        }}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest} my tree  % <---
[Root
    [Tall]
    [no \\add' info]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked, such an easy fix! Thanks. I'm strongly considering switching to `forest`, but `qtree` seems more intuitive (the settings for each `forest` tree seem a little overwhelming).

Comment: @Ernesto, `forest have similar settings as `qtree`. If you liked, you can move it to document preamble, see edited answer.

Comment: this was very helpful. Thanks!